# Locale language for google charts not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core

In my page I load the chart as described [in the docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs). It's a view in asp.net that renders the output. The view checks if a class called Avstemning is populated then puts strings from that class into the chart as data. But if I use Norwegian letters like ø,æ, å. The chart data can't read it even as I specify the language option to use. What is going on here?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

@if (Model.Avstemning != null)
{

 <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts
  .load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'], 'language':'no' });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Avstemning', '@Model.Avstemning.Tittel'],
        ['@Model.Avstemning.Option1', @Model.Avstemning.One],
        ['@Model.Avstemning.Option2', @Model.Avstemning.Two],
        ['@Model.Avstemning.Option3', @Model.Avstemning.Three]

    ]);

    var options = {
        title: '@Model.Avstemning.Tittel'};
    var chart = new 
    google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
 </script>
}
```

If I change the data variable to take hard coded options with norwegian letters it works. But that's not exactly ideal. Any ideas on how to solve this? Inject javascript from controller?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the encoding issue by using Html.Raw(). Not recommended if these are later to be stored in db, but works for displaying the data as I intended:

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Avstemning', '@Html.Raw(Model.Avstemning.Tittel)'],
        ['@Html.Raw(Model.Avstemning.Option1)', @Model.Avstemning.One],
        ['@Html.Raw(Model.Avstemning.Option2)', @Model.Avstemning.Two],
        ['@Html.Raw(Model.Avstemning.Option3)', @Model.Avstemning.Three]

    ]);

    var options = {
        title: '@Html.Raw(Model.Avstemning.Tittel)',

    };
```